"log of a Pareto random variable has an exponential distribution"
This twitter exchange below:
I'm partial to Taleb's (@Nero's) concepts, but was unfortunately not exposed to a lot of high-quality math in my childhood. As a result, I struggle to understand concepts involving log or exponential. Am trying to catch up on these concepts via YouTube.
Meanwhile, I'd really appreciate it if someone could illustrate (i.e. visualize) or otherwise explain:

the original tweet (that Taleb responded to), and why this is notable.

Taleb's response.


I'm just someone who is weak at math, but knows the value of (and values) math. Your help will go a long way in adding to math literacy.


Learn to ask Google which gave me instantly this with key words "logarithm Pareto exponential"
